# Plotting weighted distribution

Tags: r, ggplot2, weighted

Let's say I have the following data :

```
c1 <- runif(100, 0,1)
c2 <- runif(100, 0,1)
weights <- runif(100, 1,50)
categorie <- rbinom(100,1,0.5)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c1,c2,weights,categorie))
```

I would like to represent in the same plot the two distributions of c1 given that categorie=0 or given that categorie=1, and I would like to weight each observation by the variable weights. Futhermore, in y axis, I would like to have weighted proportions and not weighted numbers.

I would like to do a graph like this :
[image]

How can I do that with ggplot2?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it appears you are looking for two groups according to `categorie`. Then you want a histogram which shows the weighted percentage of each bin as it applies to each group. I would probably pre-calculate this and draw it with `geom_col`:

```r
df %>%
  reframe(x = seq(0.025, 0.975, 0.05), y = table(cut(c1, seq(0, 1, 0.05))),
          weight = tapply(weights, cut(c1, seq(0, 1, 0.05)), sum), 
          .by = categorie) %>%
  mutate(y = ifelse(is.na(y * weight), 0, y * weight)) %>%
  mutate(y = y / sum(y), .by = categorie) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = factor(categorie))) +
  geom_col(position = 'identity', alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous('Percent', labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_x_continuous('c1', breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1)) +
  scale_fill_manual('Category', values = c('orangered', 'deepskyblue4')) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what I want to do, I edited my post

Comment: @Chloe_pa that's much easier - see my update. I'm not sure now what you meant by 'I want weighted proportions, not weighted numbers'

Comment: well that's not really what I want. I want to fill my plot with categorie (which takes two values 0 or 1). Furthermore, I don't understand why on y axis the density can be greater than 1 : I would like for each value of x axis, to plot on y axis which is the weighted proportion of this value. I want percents in the y axis

Comment: @Chloe_pa you say you want percentage on the y axis, but the picture you showed is of a histogram with _density_ on the y axis, not percentage. Density can be higher than one; the only rule is that the area under the curve must sum to one. Can you explain what the y axis should represent? A percentage of _what_?

Comment: the percentage of observations in my data which take a given value of x axis. The variable I represent ranges from 0 to 1. Let's take x=0,5. In y axis, I would like to represent the proportion of observations in my data which takes this value. And I would like to weight this proportion with the variable weights

Comment: @Chloe_pa I _think_ I understand what you want now. I have updated.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I was wondering if it was possible to do it directly with ggplot2 without the pre-calculating step. Thanks!